# Border-radius not working in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, leaflet

I have a map created using Leaflet that I want to add rounded corners to. The following CSS does the job in Firefox, but not in Chrome:

```
.leaflet-container {
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Searching through previous answers, the `-webkit-border-radius` should work, but I'm still having issues. Is there another solution?

Note: On page load I CAN see the rounded corners for a split second, but then they disappear again.

Comment: Sounds like either JS changes this or some CSS that is loaded later overwrites your styles. Be good to see some more code.

Comment: Try adding z-index: 0. I read somewhere it could be an issue due to a webkit/chrome bug

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your CSS so you may have something else going on.  Can you show the issue in context? By the way you don't need the -moz, etc. anymore (http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius)

Comment: Technically, the vendor prefix versions should be **before** the standardized version.

Comment: @PersyJack your suggestion worked. Using just `border-radius: 10px;` and `z-index: 0;` did the trick. I'm not entirely sure why, but I'll look into it.

Comment: @PersyJack's comment should be made the answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

- Check the "Styles" or "Computed" tab in the Developer Tools (F12).
- It tells you whether or not the property was accepted or overwritten.
- Only accepted values show up in the Computed Tab.
- Overwritten values will have a strikethrough.
- If there is a line (strikethrough) going through the property's name,
  then something is overwriting that property.

`.leaflet-container {
    border-radius: 10px;
}`
should work in Chrome.

Also, try setting the background of the container to the image of the leaflet and then center it with `background-position: bottom center;`

Maybe you are setting the `border-radius` of the container but the image itself might be "leaking out" because of a CSS `position` setting somewhere. It has happened before...

Comment: +! Good thought about the image leaking out.

Answer (score 0):

If your border-radius is on a tag please check all attributes. When a tag has type=submit attribute it doesn't accept border radius.